# Place div below another absolute div

Tags: html, css

**This a code snippet for loading screen.**

I want to place text below the loader animation, example: **Loading**.

I am not able to place/order div correctly below the .loader1 div.

```css
.loader {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #222222;
  z-index: 1000;
}
.loader1 {
  z-index: 1001;
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #DAC500;
  border-right: 16px solid #4A6FB1;
  border-bottom: 16px solid #DAC500;
  border-left: 16px solid #4A6FB1;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loader">
  <div class="loader1"></div>
</div>
```

That's it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

.loader {
    position: absolute;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #222222;
    z-index: 1000;
}
.loader1 {
  z-index: 1001;
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #DAC500;
  border-right: 16px solid #4A6FB1;
  border-bottom: 16px solid #DAC500;
  border-left: 16px solid #4A6FB1;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
position:fixed;
display:block;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;

    margin: auto;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="loader">
LOADING ...
<div class="loader1"> </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _"I want to place text **below** the loader animation"_

Comment: the "LOADING ..." phrase is touching the top side of the screen.
I want to place it just below the loader.

Comment: @9gager replace the `Loading...` by `<p style='padding:25%'>Loading...</p>`

Answer (score 0):

Added some CSS ro your loader div and placed it under the loader. Would this be what you're looking for?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .loader {
      position: absolute;
      color: #fff;
      text-align: center;
      width: 100px;
      height: 20px;
      line-height:20px;
      padding: 5px 10px;
      top: 200px;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      margin: auto;
      background: #222222;
      z-index: 1000;
    }
    .loader1 {
      z-index: 1001;
      border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
      border-radius: 50%;
      border-top: 16px solid #DAC500;
      border-right: 16px solid #4A6FB1;
      border-bottom: 16px solid #DAC500;
      border-left: 16px solid #4A6FB1;
      width: 120px;
      height: 120px;
      -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
      animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
      position: fixed;
      display: block;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      margin: auto;
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes spin {
      0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
      }
      100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
    }
    @keyframes spin {
      0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
      }
      100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="loader">
    <div class="loader1"></div>
    Loading</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe u can do that like this:

**Demo: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Gjrgjd)**

```css
.loader {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #222222;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.loader1, .loading {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.loading {
  z-index: 1002;
  width: 90px;
  height: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}

.loading p {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.loader1 {
  z-index: 1001;
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #DAC500;
  border-right: 16px solid #4A6FB1;
  border-bottom: 16px solid #DAC500;
  border-left: 16px solid #4A6FB1;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loader">
  <div class="loader1"></div>
  <div class="loading"><p>LOADING...</p></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

We will have to take some assumptions.

The **width** and **height** of circle is fixed as it is now. Then we use **absolute position** of div containing text **Loading**. Using **margin-left, margin-top, left, top** we can play and find what is suitable of us.

```css
.loader {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #222222;
  z-index: 1000;
}
.loader1 {
  z-index: 1001;
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #DAC500;
  border-right: 16px solid #4A6FB1;
  border-bottom: 16px solid #DAC500;
  border-left: 16px solid #4A6FB1;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
.loader-text{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  color:#fff;
  margin-top:-15px;
  margin-left:-30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="loader">
  <div class="loader1"></div>
  <div class="loader-text">Loading</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change how you're doing it entirely and use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) like this.

It will work out a middle based on both the spinner and the text as opposed to having the spinner in the middle and the text below it.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.load {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: rgba(34, 34, 34, 1);
  z-index: 999;
}
.load-spinner {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 16px solid;
  border-color: #DAC500 #4A6FB1;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}
.load-text {
  text-align: center;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0)
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="load">
  <div class="load-group">
    <div class="load-spinner"></div>
    <div class="load-text">Loading...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```